# Incisive: Noun use

Tags: word-usage, nouns

Incisiveness is the noun of the incisive adjective, but in this sentence:

> Communication has to be incisive.

It seems to me that Incisiveness doesn't work here, and incisive sounds correct, although grammatically the wrong part?

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the wrong part.

"Incisive" in your sentence is a *predicate adjective*.  The "to be" attaches the subject ("communication") to its modifier ("incisive").

This is a very common construction in English.

This site http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-predicate-adjectives.html
shows many examples. Your textbook probably also dicusses *predicate adjectives*.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the sentence is perfectly right.

*Communication has to be incisive.*

Though the adjective(incisive) is not placed anywhere close to the noun(communication), the attribute of 'incisiveness' automatically belongs to 'communication'.

Like in the sentence: *Your speech must be clear* or *Her speech is fluent*.

If you still feel *incisiveness* is better, you may try this: *Incisiveness in communication is what everyone should aim for.*

Let me know if I've answered your question as you expected(because I didn't understand why you felt the sentence has a grammatical error).